# How do i convert list into DataFrame by row wise

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I store row wise data in pandas dataframe with predefined column names through a loop?
This is for text extraction from images.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1','Col2', 'Col3',  'Col4', 'Col5','Col6', 'Col7', 'Col8','Col9', 'Col10', 'Col11', 'Col12', 'Col13', 'Col14'])

for itam in dirs:
if os.path.isfile(path+itam):
    for a in x:
        img = Image.open(path+itam)
        crop = img.crop(a)
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(crop, config='--psm 4')
        for i in range(len(text)):
            df.loc[i] =  [text for n in range(14)]

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'str'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

**Expected output**

I want to store for loop data into pandas data frame with pre-defined columns, but by using above code it stores multiple copies of the same record.

```
print(df)
     col1  col2  col3 col4 col5  col6  col7 col8 col9  col10  col11 col12 col13 col14
0    0     0     1     2     3     4    5     6    8     9      10    11    12    13    
2    0     1     2     3     4    5     6    8     9      10    11    12    13    14
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `computer-vision` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html?highlight=append#pandas.DataFrame.append):

> Iteratively appending rows to a DataFrame can be more computationally intensive than a single concatenate. A better solution is to append those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original DataFrame all at once.

You can just as easily append your data to a list and instantiate the DataFrame with the list.

```py
import pandas as pd

container = []

for a in x:
    # get the text you want
    text = 'somestring'
    char_list = [i for i in text]
    container.append(char_list)

# now create your DataFrame
frame = pd.DataFrame(container, columns=['Col1','Col2', 'Col3',  'Col4', 'Col5','Col6', 'Col7', 'Col8','Col9', 'Col10', 'Col11', 'Col12', 'Col13', 'Col14'])
```

#### Example:

```py
In [1]: datlist = [[i for i in '01234567890123'] for ii in range(10)]

In [2]: datlist
Out[2]:
[['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3'],
 ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3'],
 ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3'],
 ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3'],
 ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3'],
 ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3'],
 ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3'],
 ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3'],
 ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3'],
 ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '1', '2', '3']]

In [3]: pd.DataFrame(datlist, columns=range(len(datlist[0])))
Out[3]:
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13
0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3
1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3
2  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3
3  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3
4  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3
5  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3
6  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3
7  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3
8  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3
9  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3
```

Comment: AssertionError: 14 columns passed, passed data had 74 columns @ralex

Comment: while run above code, I getting error :AssertionError: 14 columns passed, passed data had 74 columns @ralex

Comment: @pranita, you haven't provided a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question was about adding data to a DataFrame and I have tried to answer that. If your question is not answered, please explain how. Your comments above are about debugging.